# What is this build.xml doing?

Tags: ant, build.xml

I am learning build.xml and am confused by the following code:

```
  <macrodef name="a-test">
      <attribute name="port" default="${PORT}"/>        #1
      <junit printsummary=...
            <env key="PORT" value="@{port}" />          #2
            ...
```

when I run java with commandLine including -DPORT=8080 and then in java code I get port value 8080 by calling

```
String port = System.getenv(PORT).
```

What is the above build.xml doing? So far I know $ is to represent a property while @ is to represent an attribute. Besides, the above code is the only place where PORT and port appear. What happens here so that port value are finally obtained in java code? Thanks.

The other question, what is the difference btw. using "env key" and using "sysproperty"? according to http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+extreme+programming/Chapter+3.+Ant/3.6+Passing+Arguments+to+a+Buildfile/
sysproperty can be use to parse argument -D to java code, while env key is used to do the same thing right? Thanks.

Is there any detailed document about build.xml? the one I google from internet describer things so briefly.

Comment: Try getting a book on ant. : http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001841.do

Comment: Please ask once specific question, so answers will be useful. sysproperty is discussed at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) in ant. There will be another place in build.xml(or other build.xml) where this is called by like

```
<a-test port=<value> ..
```